# How to avoid refreshing the footer in mobile jquery?

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm using *Phonegap CLI* and JQM. My target platform is Android 4.

How can i avoid refreshing the datas inside the `data-role="footer"` in mobile jquery?

The contents inside the `data-role="header"` is not refreshing. This is the same kind of operation is I am looking for. The footer and header is common for me. Everything else is working fine. I am trying to load another page in iframe inside footer. The iframe loads in each page transitions.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Please provide some code so we can help you.

Comment: Since this is your first post. Is this your first App? What is your target platform and their target versions? Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ?
Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: i am using CLI and targeting the version of android is 4. I am planning to add a music player in footer. whenever ia m putting the code it plays well. but the problem is when  the page transition is taking place it is getting paused.

Comment: @Albert, your bigger issue is not being able to follow directions. *Phonegap Build* does not use CLI. Your answers should have gone in the original post. I'm fixing your post. -Best of Luck